# How to create two objects(instances) of a class, and two different ways how to use its function f()?

Tags: c++, function, class, object, instance

I'm fairly new to C++ and programming all together, and I'm now approaching OOP using classes...

How would I do this exactly?

For example:

Given a class called A which has a public instance member function called f(), create two objects (instances) from the class in two different ways and how to use f() in two different ways.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you asking how [Polymorphism](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/) works?

Comment: Or are you asking about class-members?

Comment: Read your course material or a book. If we do your homework, you won´t learn it.

Comment: I can't take you seriously.

Comment: @deviantfan Considering the wording of the "example", I think the course material is using a set of confusing terminology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first object declared on stack like this:

```
A a1;  //allocate on stack
a1.f(); //call f
```

The second option on heap:

```
 A* pA = new A();//allocate on heap
 pA->f();//call f
```